# Proper way to insert records with foreign keys in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I created a number of classes in SQLAlchemy to represent my various tables. I now want to insert records into these tables from various csv files that contain the data in an unnormalized format. What is the best way to deal with foreign keys?

In a simplified model, I have two tables: Child and Parent, with a one to many relationship. The parent table is already filled up, with a unique parent_name for each primary key. I am currently doing this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    u = session.query(Parent).filter_by(parent_name=row['parent_name']).first()
    session.add(Child(child_name=row['child_name'], parent_id=u.id))
```

Is there a way with sqlalchemy to avoid the first query? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610563/what-is-the-proper-way-to-insert-an-object-with-a-foreign-key-in-sqlalchemy) implies that using relationships is the correct/easy way to do it, but only explains the hard way.

Comment: If you don’t know the ID of the parent row and don’t have the parent object already available then you need the query.